# divide the value of a column by another column

Tags: sql, sql-function

I want to divide a value of a column by the value of another column and display the result as separate column

ex:

```
project name             total-percent        no.of screen
------------            --------------        -------------
pro-1                     150                     5
pro-2                      50                     3
```

now i want to divide total-percent by no.of screen and display the result in another column

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Select total_percent / no_of_scren as 'result' From yourTableName
```

Comment: Indeed it is just a matter of dividing ... ;)

Comment: Are there issues of integer division?

Comment: @Climbs_lika_Spyder - What do you mean? if you mean there are some fractions discarded from dividing integers, yes there are and the OP should handle this, and there is also the divide by zero issue and he should handle this by checking first before dividing.

Comment: I found my issue. I needed to `CAST( x as FLOAT)/y` to avoid the `0` result.